# Jquery Ajax redirect not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect

I have a couple of issues that I need help with. First I want the below redirect to work. However the browser does not redirect. Here is the entire contents of my jsp

```
function testAjax(){
alert("In test Ajax");
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://xyz.com/",
    data:   "param1=value1" +
        "&target=http://abc.com"
    ,
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            alert("Success ");
            window.location.href = "http://abc.com";
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("Success");
    },
    async: false
});
```

}

The parameter target is basically to xyz.com so that when that server does a redirect, it redirects to whatever is in the target. However when I invoke this javascript(by hitting a jsp) the browser does not redirect. I tried debugging on Firefox with developer tools and I see the GET request to xyz that is returning a 302 with a location header.

Comment: is the success handler getting called?

Comment: yes, the alert alert("Success ") gets invoked.

Comment: what is your server sending back as response to the AJAX request?

Comment: http://xyz.com is not my server its a different service that I talk to and not under my control, my jsp is hosted on the domain http://abc.com

Comment: stil can you not use chrome to find out what response is getting sent back?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are getting a successful response - if you see an alert saying "Success" you may not actually be okay here as you have it for both success and error:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        alert("Success ");
        window.location.href = "http://example.com";
},
error: function(data) {
    alert("Success");
},
```

I recommend something more like:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Fail " + textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
},
```

This may point you in the right direction as I'm sure the location would change if you had a real success.

My guess at the error is that you are attempting to make an AJAX call to another domain, which will be blocked by browser security. You would need to use JSONP or CORS to make a cross domain request.

Comment: lol.. good catch.. I didnt see both handlers have the same alert!

Comment: Steve, thanks. I see the error now - Fail error - [Exception... "Failure"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 4"  data: no]

Comment: So now I am attempting a cross domain "GET" ajax call. I have been researching and see the following 2 options 1. JSONP (but the server in the other domain has to support it) or have them set a header Access-Control-Allow-Origin for my domain. Are there any other viable options that I am missing?

Comment: The other alternative is to add a proxy on your server that does the remote call, so it looks local to your JavaScript. For example a PHP page that loads the remote page and echo's it out (or whatever language you prefer).